# Is there a way to preserve multi-level heading tags when pasting from MS Word into CKeditor?

Tags: wysiwyg

CKEditor is now part of Drupal (which is great).  It is now possible to deliver Drupal to clients that are frightened when they see HTML-markup!

However, some clients of this type are in love with Microsoft Word. They use MS Word as their *only* authoring tool, and just want to paste the result into the web-page to publish on their company web-site.

As everybody knows: When pasting text from Microsoft Word into CKedior (using the default `Ctrl+V` keystroke), you get a lot of garbage as part of the package. I know there are ways to clean this up (e.g. [**Paste Format**](https://www.drupal.org/project/pasteformat) and similar modules) by removing blank lines and inline styles. This is not a problem.

However, if your MS Word document is set up with *multi-level* headings, these are transformed into list items by the standard `Ctrl+V` keystroke to paste. This means that a level one heading in Word that appear to the user as this:

## 7 Chapter

becomes a list:

```
<ol start="7">
  <li>Chapter</li>
</ol>
```

Worse, lower level headings, such as:

### 7.1 Sub-section

become HTML nested lists.

However, Adobe's *Dreamweaver* is capable of preserving this type of multi-level heading if you paste using its [Insert Document dialog box](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/import-microsoft-office-documents-windows.html). What you get if you do this in DreamWeaver, is HTML that is very similar to what you get when you use “Save as” in MS Word and “Save as type: Web page, filtered”. I.e. MS Word multi-level headings is preserved as HTML-headings. The two examples above become:

```
<h1>7 Chapter</h1>
<h2>7.1 Sub-section</h2>
```

Extending **Paste Format**, etc. to undo this damage is not possible, as it is not possible to tell the difference between multi-level headings transformed into multi-level lists, and actual multi-level lists.

My question is: Is there a way to preserve multi-level heading tags when *pasting* from MS Word into CKeditor? Or: Is there a way to use “Paste special” or some other Microsoft magic to get the *right type* of HTML when you paste from MS Word into CKEditor?

**PS**:
I understand that a work-around would be to take the round trip via MS Word's “Save as type: Web page, filtered”, and paste the resulting file (via Notepad) into CKeditor in its “Source” mode. However, the client is unhappy about this detour via the file system and wants paste from MS Word into CKEditor to work “just as seamless as it does in Dreamweaver”. Is this possible?

Comment: Dreamweaver is not an authoring tool, it is an IDE. It doesn't care about tag restrictions or cleanup on paste like CKEditor, sounds like their expectations need alignment.